# Stern Gerlach experiment - only two discrete beams?

Tags: angular-momentum, quantum-spin, electrons

[The Stern Gerlach experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment) was meant to prove the orbital quantization of electrons where there should be +ml,0,-ml states. So for l=2, there should be 5 beams.

But they saw 2 beams, which was shown to be due to the 2 states of spin.

Now, because of the addition of the spin magnetic moment, shouldn't there be now 10 beams?(2 additional states for each the 5 orbital states).

What happened to the orbital magnetic contribution?

Comment: See this post and the answer: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33021/why-silver-atoms-were-used-in-stern-gerlach-experiment

Comment: Sometimes it's only the largest effect that gets observed.