# Why free electron has orbital magnetic moment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons

I was about to ask why don't we use electron beam instead of atoms in Stern-Gerlach experiment, then I saw [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33021/) and my question become why free electron has orbital magnetic moment...

Comment: "free" is in contrast to "bound in an atom". In the link they are talking electron beans  in magnetic fields, and there the electron has a curvature  (Bqv=mv**2/r for the perpendicular case )which will give rise to a magnetic moment.